# Tinymce 4 - Add class to <p> tag that added automatically when press Enter Key

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

In Tinymce 4 editor, the p tag added automatically to new line when press Enter Key. As I want to add class "no-margin" to `<p>` tag to apply margin 0 to the `<p>` tag that added automatically when press Enter Key.

I have tried to add class to `<p>` tag when pressed Enter Key but its not working when set cursor at middle of content and press Enter Key.

```
ed.on('keyup', function(event) {    
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
        tinymce.each(ed.dom.select('p'), function(element) {                
            if(!jQ(element).next('p').length) {                             
                ed.dom.addClass(element, 'no-margin');          
            }
        });                 
    }
});
```

Please suggest solution, thanks

Comment: I have solution after going through tinymce doc to add class to forced root block <p> tag, https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#forced_root_block_attrs Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try to add this settings:

- forced_root_block : 'p',
- forced_root_block_attrs: { "class": "no-margin"},